# node, req.files me sale como null

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, express, requests

Buenas estoy haciendo una web nodejs y express, y al subir una img al servidor no me llega, me retorna un null en el req.files, este es mi código:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const hbs = require("hbs");
const path = require("path");
const sql = require("mssql");
const { config } = require("../db/db");
const session = require("express-session");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const { login } = require('./functions/login');
const { URladministrador } = require('./functions/login');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(fileUpload());

hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname, "../", "/views/partials"));



app.post("/nuevaActa", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    let body = req.body;
    let acta = req.files.acta;
});
```

Este es mi js con el mando la imagen al servidor:

```
$('#formNuevaActa').submit(function() {
    let datasend = new FormData($("#formNuevaActa")[0]);
    let nuevaActa = async() => {
        await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/nuevaActa',
            data: datasend,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res == 1) {
                    alert('El acta se ha creado con éxito');
                    location.href = "";
                    return 1;
                } else if (res == 0) {
                    alert('Ha ocurrido un error, inténta subir el acta de nuevo mas tarde');
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    nuevaActa().then(acta => {
        console.log(acta);
        return false;
    }).catch(e => console.log('error al crear el acta', e));
    return false;
});
```

y este mi formulario:

```
<form id="formNuevaActa" action="/nuevaActa" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Título</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control tituloActa" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Introduzca título"
                name="titulo">
            </div>
          
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tipo documento</label>
              <select class="custom-select" name="tipoDocumento" id="tipoDocumento" required>
                <option hidden>Seleccione tipo</option>
                 
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputFile">Archivo</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" required max-size="2000" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" class="custom-file-input"
                    id="exampleInputFile" name="acta">
                  <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Seleccione archivo</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="text-muted">Tamaño máximo de archivo 2MB</span>
              <br>
              <span class="text-muted">Formatos de archivo aceptados .pdf, .doc y .docx</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cancelarNuevoActa" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success subirActa" data-dismiss="modal">Subir documento</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal? no logro encontrar el error, siempre me retorna null el req.files, y me dice que no puede leer acta de null, ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si no me equivoco esta en req.body . Hace console.log(req.body) y si no busca haciendo console.log(req) en que parte se encuentra el file.

Comment: Buenas, en req.body no me sale y no encuentro ningún otro sitio, antes si que me funcionaba pero al retomar el proyecto me he encontrado con que esto ahora no funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: copia y pega todo el json que te tira console.log(req)

Comment: Es demasiado largo, pero busco req.files y me sale así: {}

Comment: Estoy seguro que está en req.body busca bien

Comment: Al ser un archivo, en body no aparece ya que es de tipo file, en req.body me salen los dos valores que son texto

Comment: Intenta con req.files.FormFieldName;  // En tu caso creo que iría acta

Comment: no, porque me dice que no detecta acta de null